# android elevation hiding all view of the layout

Tags: android, shadow, android-elevation

I have layout as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Code I have is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normalxx"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        .......
```

Now I want to add shadow for the box so I have as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <TextView
        style="@style/shadowStyle"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ll_main"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ll_main"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/ll_main"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/ll_main"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normalxx"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        android:orientation="vertical">
```

`shadowStyle` is as below.

```
<style name="shadowStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:text"></item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/myrect</item>
    <item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor">@color/shadow_color</item>
</style>
```

And `myrect.xml` shape as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

When I add this all below view gets hidden which is weird.

App screenshots are as below.

[image]

I give `shadow_color` as `#FF00FF` for testing purpose only.

### Any idea how to make it proper? Am I missing something...

Comment: make it inside a card you would be able to control the shadow. the why it's hiding part its cuz you elevating the whole layout and it gonna hide every thing under it

Comment: @MãĴď : But linear I have is above TextView so it should not have come over it.. Linear is above TV...

Comment: @MãĴď : `make it inside a card` more details please... or can you post an answer...

Comment: @MãĴď : I tried CardView instead of textview and same result...

Comment: I cant post a solution cuz your xml doesn't recreate the issue you are dealing with.

Comment: @MãĴď : I got the solution & understood now... I will post shortly...

Comment: sure. alright !

Comment: @MãĴď : Thanks for your kind help... Appreciated...

Comment: @MãĴď : One favor.. Can I get proper link explaining why my code didn't work and why have to use CardView?

Comment: the optimal way to such thing is to use Cardview.

this link help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910515/why-use-a-cardview-instead-of-a-relativelayout-or-linearlayout

this one too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794725/advantage-and-disadvantage-of-cardview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is what I did as per [mãĴď](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17677301/m%c3%a3%c4%b4%c4%8f) comments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_normalxx"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_smallxx"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/shadow_color"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            ........
        </LinearLayout>
    </CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This means we will have card view and put whole layout inside it...

Answer (score 0):

1. add this style in your `theme.xml`

```kotlin
<style name="SpecificCornerRounded">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">50dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">50dp</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopLeft">rounded</item>
</style>
```

2. Also, add this xml file in your drawble `rounded_rectangle_stroked.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#1886f7"/>
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Now, here is your final code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:cardElevation="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_stroked"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/addidas"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SpecificCornerRounded" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                android:text="Expiring: 01-12-24"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="More"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="#b8243d"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: output]

- Using scrollview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#EDEDED"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:cardElevation="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_stroked"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/addidas"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SpecificCornerRounded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:text="Expiring: 01-12-24"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#b8243d"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:cardElevation="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_stroked"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/addidas"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SpecificCornerRounded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:text="Expiring: 01-12-24"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#b8243d"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke1"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            app:cardElevation="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_stroked"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/addidas"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.496"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SpecificCornerRounded" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:text="Expiring: 01-12-24"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="More"
                    android:textColor="#b8243d"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imvCornerRadiusWithStroke4"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView5" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

- Screenshot:

[image: using scrollview]

***Hope it helps!***